# UITableViewCell swipe left to right show buttons

Tags: ios, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

When a `UITableViewCell` is swiped `right to left`, `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:` gets fired and `delete button` is shown on the right side of `UITableViewCell`.

I wish to do the same when user swipes from `left to right`-> show `Delete and More` buttons `horizontally split`.

I am following [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qmajopkacrido29/SwipeTableCell.zip) project which works as per my requirement. My query is that how do I make the Custom Buttons split `horizontally` i.e. `Delete button above More button`.

If you download the code and run it, then in `SWUtilityButtonView.m` you will see the following code:

```
- (void)setUtilityButtons:(NSArray *)utilityButtons{

if (!precedingView)
        {
            // First button; pin it to the left edge.
            [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[button]"
                                                                         options:0L
                                                                         metrics:nil
                                                                           views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(button)]];
        }
        else
        {
            // Subsequent button; pin it to the right edge of the preceding one, with equal width.
            [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[precedingView][button(==precedingView)]"
                                                                         options:0L
                                                                         metrics:nil
                                                                           views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(precedingView, button)]];
        }

        [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[button]|"
                                                                     options:0L
                                                                     metrics:nil
                                                                       views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(button)]];
}
```

What modifications should I make to these constraints so as to align the `UIButtons` one above other?

Comment: Have you tried this one https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell

Comment: @d3p0nit- yeah its the same. My query is how do I get the buttons to be placed one above other?